# Any active browser intermittently freezes after using it for a while - how to diagnose?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, browser, freeze

I have a really weird issue that I have no idea how to diagnose. I'm a developer and have both Chrome and Firefox installed. I primarily use Chrome, but for a while now Chrome has had an intermittent problem where after using it for a while (could be 5 minutes, could be 8 hours), it'll suddenly freeze. It then stays frozen for a few minutes, after while it becomes active again until it receives focus, at which point it freezes again. Things I tried included disabling all plugins, all extensions, gpu, and so forth, but nothing seems to do the trick. Rebooting the computer seems to make the problem go away - for a while. Incognito mode seems to work ok, but I can't open any settings because those do not open in incognito mode, so a freeze is then triggered. If I sit there with shift held down and chrome in focus and wait a few minutes until it gets its moment of cpu time, I can then hit ESC to bring up the Chrome task manager, which doesn't seem to freeze until I switch out of it. While it's open I can try killing different extension processes and so forth. Sometimes killing my Hangouts extension will fix things, but it's not a consistent solution.

Here's why I don't think the problem is actually Chrome - Recently I got fed up with having to reboot and started using Firefox when Chrome froze, but I noticed that after using Firefox for a while, *it* would freeze, and Chrome would suddenly become responsive again! In fact, I'm writing this in Chrome write now, because Firefox is frozen in the background; whatever was freezing Chrome obviously forgot about Chrome and decided to focus on Firefox instead. I even experienced this with the Edge browser (I'm on Windows 10, though the problem started while I was still on Windows 8.1).

I have both Malwarebytes (paid) active, and Windows' own antivirus running. Neither of those are reporting that I have any malware, viruses or otherwise.

I've been a programmer/geek for most of my life and I can usually figure out how to solve problems on my computer, but this one has me stumped.

[image]

[image]

**Edit**
I killed a whole lot of processes, including some Intel and Asus (AI Suite rubbish) processes that do things like network enhancement, motherboard monitoring, USB optimization and a bunch of other seemingly-unnecessary stuff, and shortly after, both browsers started working again. I'm not entirely sure if something I killed was the problem, but I'll try it again next time I boot up.

Comment: Do you have any internet security software installed?

Comment: I've similar problem with Windows 10. Checkout your RAM usage

Comment: @Sachith see 3rd paragraph

Comment: @Kumar Got plenty of RAM (16GB, with no more than half in use)

Comment: How about reinstalling browsers??  Also try safe mode with networking. Do you face this on all websites or specific sites??

Comment: @Kumar reinstalling had no effect. Safe mode did not help. It happens on all websites.

Comment: I am having the same issue with Windows 10

Comment: even years later, it can be used for someone - search about usb autosuspend or any similar behavior. My whole system was hatling,  even no browser open (in linux however). I had halting issues with any browser left open. I think processors may "deactivate" processes or data from memory for energy consumption or similar. Also, you may clear cached directories of browers (mine went to 60GB each!). Good luck!